# How to group rows and select a "sample" match in one go

Tags: sql, group-by, derby

I have a table in a Derby database of the form of

```
Status   Name
0        Name1
0        Name2
1        Name3
1        Name4
2        NameX
...
```

I use the following to summarize how often each status happens

```
SELECT COUNT(*), STATUS
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY STATUS
```

Now I would like to add one sample-name for each status (does not matter which one), i.e. I would like a result similar to

```
Count    Status     Sample
2        0          Name2
2        1          Name3
1        2          NameX
...
```

I tried using sub-query together with ROW_NUMBER(), but couldn't get it to work.

So is there a way to write a SQL statement which includes one name from the data as shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to make the names "random", if not, you could try

```
select count(*), max(Name), Status
from MYTABLE
group by Status
```

Comment: I went with MIN(), but that did the trick quite nicely, thanks!

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*), STATUS, name AS sample FROM mytable
GROUP BY status will also work (no min or max required).

Comment: You must be a golfer if you prefer `min` to `max` :)